# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 179) dont fun

Tags: laravel

I have a problem in laravel, I have developed a system that worked correctly the routes, but now it does not work any route all give me the same result error.

Esta mi archivo app.blade.php

```
<li>
      <a href={{url('home')}} class="dropdown-toggle"> 
           <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
           <span class="hidden-xs">Panel</span>
          </a>
</li>
```

This is my web.php file

```
 Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('home');
    });

Route::get('/home', 'PruebaController@index')->name('home');
```

this is my Controller file

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PruebaController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

[php artisan route:list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4bQz.png)
I have reviewed everything but I do not find the problem, everything seems to be correct, what I did was to clone the project have something to do.

Comment: make sure you have a home.blade.php file inside of resources/views

Comment: If the file exists within the view directory

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60247545/8484740

Answer (score 0):

Dou yo have view->home.blade.php?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you have `cloned the project`, I think its got to do with cache.

Try

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: f I thought it was the cache but I performed the operations:

Comment: everything with success, I have also reviewed and if there is the file home.blade.php within Resources> Views

Answer (score 0):

I followed the error to the file RouteColletion.php in the function matchAgainstRoutes when I print the $ request, the last variables

```
        Request {#38 ▼
    ...    
        pathInfo: "/ gesis / public / home"
        requestUri: "/ gesis / public / home"
        baseUrl: ""
        basePath: ""
        format: "html" 
}
```

I leave empty I think that's why but I do not know why I leave these variables empty.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected it thanks to all, the problem was the simple truth but I could not see the directive APP_NAME = geSis of the file .env changed the uppercase S by the small one so it did not encintrace the route.
I thanked them for their time and I received a lot of comments.