# Laravel (1/1) NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've encountered a problem submitting my form in laravel.  My form structure looks this.

```
<form  class="form-group" action="{{ route('writepoem') }}" 
method="post" name="publish" enctype="multipart/form-data"  
onsubmit="return validateForm();">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
   <input type="text" name="user">
   <textarea name="poem"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

My web.php file has this route.

```
Route::post('/writepoem', ['uses'=>'PoemController@postCreatePoem','as'=>'writepoem']);
```

My PoemController.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Poem;

class PoemController extends Controller
{ 
    public function postCreatePoem(Request $request)
    {   
        //validation
        $poem=new Poem();
        $poem->poem=$request['poem'];
        $poem->user=$request['user'];



        //save poem
        $request->user()->poems()->save($poem);
        return redirect()->route('feed');
    }
}
```

On submitting my form I get this Exception.

(1/1) NotFoundHttpException

in RouteCollection.php line 179.

What could be the issue with routing?

Comment: Is the Poem getting created? Could be an issue with `return redirect()->route('feed');`. Also, `$poem->poem=$request['poem']; $poem->poem=$request['user'];` doesn't look right; you're setting `$poem->poem` twice, to different variables. Also, haven't seen `$request["poem"];`; not sure if an issue, but I usually use `$request->input("poem")` or `$request->poem` (avoid the second usage for `$request->input("user");`)

Comment: @TimLewis No the poem is not getting created, it throws the Exception NotFoundHttpException.

Comment: First, csrf_token is missing (but that's not the issue over here probably).
What is the actual action of the form? could you check and let us know?

Comment: Hmm... At a glance, everything looks ok; Route is named correctly, (you'd be getting an error otherwise), using the correct method (`="post"` for `Route::post()`). Try `{{ url("/writepoem") }}` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @TimLewis I've tried {{ url("/writepoem") }} but I'm still getting the exception.

Comment: @MyLibary the csrf is present in the original form

Comment: Show the actual HTML rendered code, is that possible?

Comment: @Erickioko Change your csrf field to   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">  try now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my form was linked to the main page via

```
`require resource_path().'/sub-folder/write.php'`
```

and that was causing the error.

I moved the form to the main document and my issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If your route points site.com/writepoem and this route returns notfoundexception; this means 2 possible things;

1) Your route has a group and this group has a parent namespace for url

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'poems'], function() {
    Route::post('/writepoem', ['uses'=>'PoemController@postCreatePoem','as'=>'writepoem']);
});
```

2) Or your route file is cached. please try; `php artisan route:clear` & `php artisan route:cache`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but now I fixed my problem.

You need to follow these steps. If you have written the right code and then you get this error, then you need to follow steps.

1. Clear cache `php artisan route:clear` & `php artisan route:cache` run command one by one. If your problem not fixed yet then you need to follow the second step also
2. Run this command to reload composer `composer dump-autoload`